# Concerning the Rite of Christian Initiation of Adults

Tags: catholicism, baptism, sacraments, confirmation

Why do the American and Canadian [Rites of Initiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rite_of_Christian_Initiation_of_Adults) differ in numbering and in the way that the rites are sometimes celebrated?

Comment: You need to explain in a bit more detail what you mean by "the rites are sometimes celebrated" ... your point of comparison is invisible.

Answer (score 2):

The Canadian and American Rites of Christian Initiation differ because it is basically permitted by Rome.

> ADAPTATIONS BY THE CONFERENCES OF BISHOPS IN THE USE OF THE ROMAN RITUAL
>
> 32. In addition to the adaptations envisioned in Christian Initiation, General Introduction (nos.30-33), the rite of Christian initiation of adults allows for other adaptations that will be decided by the conference of bishops.
> 33. Each conference of bishops has discretionary power to make the following decisions:
> 34. to establish for the precatechumenate, where it seems advisable, some way of receiving inquirers who are interested in the catechumenate (see no. 39);
> 35. to insert into the rite of acceptance into the order of catechumens a first exorcism
>       and a renunciation of false worship, in regions where paganism is widespread (see nos.
>       69-72);
> 36. to decide that in the same rite the tracing of the sign of the cross upon the forehead (nos. 54-55) be replaced by making that sign in front of the forehead, in regions where the act of touching may not seem proper;
> 37. to decide that in the same rite candidates receive a new name in regions where it is the practice of non-Christian religions to give a new name to initiates immediately (no. 73);
> 38. to allow within the same rite, according to local customs, additional rites that symbolize reception into the community (no. 74);
> 39. to establish during the period of the catechumenate, in addition to the usual rites
>       (nos. 81-97), ‘rites of passage’: for example, early celebration of the presentations (nos. 144-150, 165-171), the ephphetha rite (nos. 184-186), the catechumens’ recitation of the Creed (nos. 180-183), or even an anointing of the catechumens (nos. 98-102);
> 40. to decide on the omission of the anointing with the oil of catechumens (no. 218) or
>       its transferral to the preparation rites for Holy Saturday (nos. 190-194) or its use during
>       the period of the catechumen ate as a kind of ‘rite of passage’ (nos. 98-100);
> 41. to make more specific and detailed the formularies of renunciation for the rite of acceptance into the order of catechumens (nos. 70-72) and for the celebration of baptism (no. 217).
>
> [Rite of Christian Initiation of Adults](https://www.liturgyoffice.org.uk/Resources/Rites/RCIA.pdf)

Individuals bishops are also allowed to make further adaptions if deemed fitting.

Further insight can be obtained in this Vatican document: [INTERNATIONAL COUNCIL FOR CATECHESIS ADULT CATECHESIS IN THE CHRISTIAN COMMUNITY SOME PRINCIPLES AND GUIDELINES](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cclergy/documents/rc_con_cclergy_doc_14041990_acat_en.html).